# error localStorage reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, redux

hi i have this code for start a session, i need save the info the user in localStorage after the login

```
    'use strict';
    const defaultState ={
        permission: localStorage.getItem('email') ? localStorage.getItem('email') : null

     }

    export const signInReducer = (state=defaultState, action)=>{
        switch (action.type){
            case 'SIGNIN_REQUEST':
                return state;
            case 'SIGNIN_FAILURE':
                return state;
            case 'SIGNIN_SUCCES':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {

                    permission: action.payload.email ? JSON.stringify(action.payload.email) : null

                })

            default:
                return state;
        }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: hi, but dont save the info to the user in the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save to `localStorage` in your reducers. These should be pure and have no side effects.

Try doing it in your action creator:

```
const signInSucess = (user) => {
  localStorage.setItem('permission', user)
  //your code...
  return { type: "SIGNIN_SUCCES", payload: user }
}
```